# Filtering the cart items based on Products in db

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey guys this is my first project that i am making with Nodejs and js (ofcos). 
So i reached the point where before displaying the products stored in user cart to the user i want to check if the Product still exists in the db or it has been removed and if it has been removed from db i do not want to show that product in user cart

So in mongoose method

```
userschema.methods.checkcart = function(product) {
 let products=product
  console.log(products) //stores all products that exist in db
};
```

gives me

```
[
  {
    _id: 5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da,
    title: 'Pepsi',
    imageurl: 'https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_26aa6df7-2fdf-4b4b-9f3b-d2ea31b5d685?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg',
    price: 12,
    description: 'Hard !',
    userid: 5d31e70115a10b1b5f7e6ed6,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db,
    title: 'Burger!',
    imageurl: 'https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg',
    price: 123,
    description: 'Tasty.',
    userid: 5d31e70115a10b1b5f7e6ed6,
    __v: 0
  },
]
```

now i want to look for the products that user has on the cart so

```
let cartproducts=this.cart.items
console.log(cartproducts) //gives

[
    {
        "_id": "5d322eb241f5e836068485db",
        "productid": "5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d322ec041f5e836068485dc",
        "productid": "5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d322ec741f5e836068485dd",
        "productid": "5d31f0636f2a111ebd6e98dc",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

Now as u can see that product with id  **5d31f0636f2a111ebd6e98dc** has been removed from db so i wanna filter them and return only those products which are in cart and db.

P.s - Tried hell lot with map and filter method but everytime created a mess !
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const products = [
  {
    _id: '5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da',
    title: 'Pepsi',
    imageurl: 'https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_26aa6df7-2fdf-4b4b-9f3b-d2ea31b5d685?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg',
    price: 12,
    description: 'Hard !',
    userid: '5d31e70115a10b1b5f7e6ed6',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db',
    title: 'Burger!',
    imageurl: 'https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg',
    price: 123,
    description: 'Tasty.',
    userid: '5d31e70115a10b1b5f7e6ed6',
    __v: 0
  },
];

const cartProducts = [
    {
        "_id": "5d322eb241f5e836068485db",
        "productid": "5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d322ec041f5e836068485dc",
        "productid": "5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d322ec741f5e836068485dd",
        "productid": "5d31f0636f2a111ebd6e98dc",
        "quantity": 1
    }
];

const productIds = products.map(prod => prod._id);
const filteredCartProducts = cartProducts
  .filter(prod => productIds.includes(prod.productid));
console.log(filteredCartProducts);
```

Comment: thanks @Rocky i should have thought of includes..my bad :p

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

With `products` beign an array, you need to go over all elements to find out if it contains it. That doesn't perform good with bigger datasets.

Just the filtered cart items:

```
cartproducts.filter(item => products.some(product => product._id === item.productid))
```

You probably want both together, the cart items and the products. That could be achieved like so:

```
cartproducts
  .map(item => ({
    item,
    product: products.find(product => product._id === item.productid),
  }))
  .filter(both => both.product)
```

(`filter` after the `map`, to not search the `products` array twice.)

By using `find` and `some` instead of `includes` as in Rocky Sims answer, you don't need an extra `productIds` array.

---

Normally in a database you would have an index on the `_id`, so that it is fast to find.

Instead of an array, your `products` could be an object where the keys are the `_id` of the products:

```
const productsById = {
  5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da: {
    _id: '5d31f00d6f2a111ebd6e98da',
    title: 'Pepsi',
    // [...]
  },
  5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db: {
    _id: '5d31f0486f2a111ebd6e98db',
    title: 'Burger!',
    // [...]
  },
}
```

The `products` array could be converted to an object like this:

```
const productsById = products.reduce(
  (map, product) => {
    map[product._id] = product
    return map
  },
  {}
)
```

Then it would be very easy and performant to filter:

```
cartproducts.filter(item => item.productid in productsById)
```

Both:

```
cartproducts
  .filter(item => item.productid in productsById)
  .map(item => ({
    item,
    product: productsById[item.productid],
  }))
```